# Retrieve data from two different rows in a single SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've a table with the following data

[image]

and I need to find the number of minutes between two jobs (Say A and C).

The following query works but wondering, if there is a simpler way to achieve the same.

```
DECLARE @StartTime datetime
Declare @EndTime datetime
set @StartTime = (SELECT start_time from table where jobname = 'A' )
set @EndTime = (SELECT end_time from table where  jobname = 'C' )
select datediff(minute,@StartTime, @EndTime) numberOfMinutes
```

Goal is to achieve, the difference between start time and end time of two jobs.

Comment: if your code is working, to review your code, you can use https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: So, you want the difference between the MINIMUM Start_Time and the MAXIMUM End_Time?

Comment: No, I want the difference between two start time and end time of two jobs.

Comment: Edit your question and show the results you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can interpret your question in two ways.  The first would be the time difference from job A to job C.  That would be the end time of A to the start time of C:

```
select datediff(minute,
                max(case when job = 'A' then endtime end),
                max(case when job = 'C' then starttime end)
               )
from t
where job in ('A', 'C');
```

Alternatively, you might be asking:  "What is the difference in *duration* between the jobs?"

```
select sum(case when job = 'A'
                then datediff(minute, starttime, endtime)
                else -datediff(minute, starttime, endtime) 
           end)
from t
where job in ('A', 'C');
```

Both of these assume that A and C only appear once in the table.  If not, you should ask a *new* question and be clearer about what you really want to do.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you:

```
select datediff(minute,
                max(case when job = 'A' then endtime end),
                max(case when job = 'C' then starttime end)
               )
from t
where job in ('A', 'C');
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work as per your need.

```
;WITH JobTable AS
(
    SELECT *
    FROM (VALUES('A', CAST('10/10/2020 08:00' AS DATETIME), CAST('10/10/2020 08:15' AS DATETIME))
                , ('B', CAST('10/10/2020 08:15' AS DATETIME), CAST('10/10/2020 08:17' AS DATETIME))
                , ('C', CAST('10/10/2020 08:17' AS DATETIME), CAST('10/10/2020 08:19' AS DATETIME))
        ) AS D (Job, Start_Time, End_Time) 
        
)
SELECT DATEDIFF (MINUTE 
                 , (MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'A' THEN Start_Time END))
                 , (MAX(CASE WHEN Job = 'C' THEN End_Time END))
                )
FROM JobTable Data
```